# Sending JSON Data from $http to Node JS Express restful service

Tags: json, node.js

What is the best way to send data from Angular js to node js restful service which uses express. My Angular js code is as follows:-

```
var myController = function("myController", $scope) {
$http.get("/someUrl", {key1:"value1", key2: "value2"}).then(function(response) { alert(response.data);});
```

On the Node js end :-

```
app.get("/someUrl", function(req, res) {console.log(req.body);});
```

I can see that console.log is displaying {}. Is there a way to send the json input for get as well.

By the way for Nodejs I used express module, I have used body-parser and set all the other things needed.

I am using Angularjs 1.4 and Nodejs express 4.

Comment: My friend asked me the Question for a use case where he want's to hit a restful service to authenticate the user's credentials. I am not sure if using params like `$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/url',
  params: params }) `is a good option or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `$resource` and `$http`. With `$resource` you can leverage the consistency of REST APIs, since it will use the familiar structure to build the endpoints, so there's a little magic going on.

Using `$resource`:

```
var Dog = $resource('/dogs/:dogId', { dogId :'@id' });

var fido = new Dog({ name: "Fido" });
fido.$save();

// POST to /dogs/ with data: { name: "Fido" }
```

With `$http` you're more explicit. You can send data like this:

```
$http({
    method: "get",
    url: "...",
    params: {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2"
    }
});
```

And like this:

```
$http({
    method: "post",
    url: "...",
    data: {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in your node server now its

```
app.get("/someUrl", function(req, res) {console.log(req.body);});
```

try this

```
app.get("/someUrl", function(req, res) {console.log(req.body.key1);});
```

Comment: The answer can become more valuable if you are adding some explanation and links to documentation, so the original poster and other users can actually learn from it.